# Appointment starts at the beginning of the calendar?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am attempting to generate an appointment from a VBA macro and put it into a calendar in Outlook. my code is below...

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1
    Dim olapp As Object
    Dim OLNS As Object
    Dim OLAppointment As Object


    On Error Resume Next
    Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If olapp Is Nothing Then Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not olapp Is Nothing Then

        Set OLNS = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        OLNS.Logon

        Set OLAppointment = olapp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        OLAppointment.Subject = "Request for Leave"
        OLAppointment.Start = TimeValue(TextBox7.Text)
        OLAppointment.End = TimeValue(TextBox10.Text)

        OLAppointment.Location = "Leave"
        OLAppointment.Body = "Request for Leave"
        OLAppointment.Save

         'Set OLAppointment = olapp.Move(olfolder)

        Set OLAppointment = Nothing
        Set OLNS = Nothing
        Set olapp = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that the appointment gets dated to begin on the 'Sat 30/12/1899' and only lasts for half an hour when i need it to last for the duration of days between the two dates as an all day appointment throughout, (Start date : TextBox7)(End date : TextBox10).

Another issue is how would i send this request to someone?

The appointment details are from an Excel UserForm's text fields

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeValue doesn't seem to allow you to include the date, only the time of day. If you set the start and end times with the below formats, for example, then it does work.

```
OLAppointment.Start = #11/26/2012 1:00:00 PM#
OLAppointment.End = #11/26/2012 2:00:00 PM#
```